# How to build Tesseract OCR library for Android Studio?

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, ocr, tess-two

I was trying to build the tesseract ocr library for android studio, i used the tutorilas present on the internet they contains some commands that to be run on cmd. But, the problem is that i am not getting how to exactly run these codes because i have downloaded ndk in my D drive then how will be able to use commands in my project directory. Please anyone tell me steps of running those commands. I have been through so many tutorilas since last three days but still i am not able to build. The commands i have found are,
git clone git://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two tess
cd tess
cd tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path .
ant release

Answer (score 4):

Building the tess-two project for using Tesseract on Android is unnecessary because there is now a pre-built version available.

If you look at the ["Usage" section of the Readme](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage), it shows how to integrate the project with your app as an external dependency by adding a line to the "dependencies" section of your app's build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:6.0.3'
```

This tells Android Studio to fetch the pre-built version of the library from the remote Maven repository where it has been published.

Once you've done this, you can use the Tesseract API in your app in the same way as if you'd built the library yourself using ndk-build.

Comment: @rmtheis Hello, Do you mean "just create a new blank Android Studio project and add `compile 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:7.0.0'` to the app module's `build.gradle` file" and that's it? Do you mean "no need to download or clone this [link](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)"

Comment: @ridoy Have you successfully built the Tesseract OCR library for Android Studio? Could you please see my comment for "rmtheis" too?

Comment: yes @Joshua, i was successful at that time, just add 'com.rmtheis:tess-two:7.0.0' in your build.gradle file.